# INSERT INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas amigos tengo dudas sobre como crear una sentencia select inner join en pdo

realice esta funcion con pdo que si realiza la insercion con una sola tabla

```
public function insertaUsuario(objeto_usuario $usuario){
    $stmt = $this->Conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (Cedula, Clave, Nombre, Sector) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
    $arrParams=array( $usuario->getCedula() ,  $usuario->getClave() , $usuario->getNombre() , $usuario->getSector() ); 
    $stmt->execute($arrParams);
    }
```

Pero estoy confundido sobre como realizar la misma funcion de insert pero con estas dos tablas es decir con un inner join, probe de algunas maneras en la sentencia pero no me funciono o me realizo alguna accion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Quieres insertar en las dos tablas a la vez? ¿quieres seleccionar datos de una tabla para insertarlos en otra? ¿Qué criterios se deben cumplir?